# Converting number to string and adding a character in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add a character onto the end of a string using

```
CASE
WHEN PackageNum = 2 THEN to_char(DespatchNum + 'B')
    WHEN PackageNum = 3 THEN to_char(DespatchNum + 'C')
       WHEN PackageNum = 4 THEN to_char(DespatchNum + 'D')
            WHEN PackageNum = 5 THEN to_char(DespatchNum + 'E')
           ELSE to_char(DespatchNum)
```

END as ShipmentReference,

However I am getting the error

> ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.

DespatchNum is a number

As an example, output would look like **1234B**

Help appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Ideal result 1234B

Comment: To concatenate characters in Oracle, you use '||' and not '+', as in select x||'A' ... and use to_char(x)||'A' if x is numeric, and you can add a format to have comma separator, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT packagenum,
       despatchnum,
       CASE PackageNum
       WHEN 2 THEN DespatchNum || 'B'
       WHEN 3 THEN DespatchNum || 'C'
       WHEN 4 THEN DespatchNum || 'D'
       WHEN 5 THEN DespatchNum || 'E'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(DespatchNum)
       END as ShipmentReference
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( packagenum, despatchnum ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 1234 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

Outputs:

> | PACKAGENUM | DESPATCHNUM | SHIPMENTREFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1234 | 1234 |
> | 2 | 1234 | 1234B |
> | 3 | 1234 | 1234C |
> | 4 | 1234 | 1234D |
> | 5 | 1234 | 1234E |
> | 6 | 1234 | 1234 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ecb652c4e6bb5afc84557be8d18d0a1)*

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @gsalem in the comments, the concatenation was incorrect and to concatonate characters onto a string you have use || not +

Answer (score 0):

You can also factor out `TO_CHAR(DESPATCHNUM)`, since it's common to all cases.

Something like this:

```
with
  tbl (packagenum, despatchnum) as (
    select 2, 3002 from dual union all
    select 5, 4122 from dual union all
    select 7, 8320 from dual
  )
select packagenum, despatchnum,
       to_char(despatchnum) || 
            case packagenum when 2 then 'B'
                            when 3 then 'C'
                            when 4 then 'D'
                            when 5 then 'E' end as shipmentreference
from   tbl
;

PACKAGENUM DESPATCHNUM  SHIPMENTREFERENCE
---------- -----------  -----------------
         2        3002  3002B                                    
         5        4122  4122E                                    
         7        8320  8320
```